# Calculating the Checksum in the receiver

Tags: networking, binary, hex, checksum

I'm reading the book [Data Communications and Networking 4th Edition Behrouz-Forouzan](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/57226587/Data-Communications-and-Networking-4th---Behrouz-Forouzan). I have a question in an exercise that asked me the following: The receiver of a message uses the checksum technique (Checksum) for 8-bit characters and get the following information

> 100101000011010100101000

. How I can know if the Data sent is correct or not? and why?

I Learned how to calculate the checksum in hexadecimal values, but do not understand as determined by a binary output, if the information is correct.

Comment: What algorithm is being used ? Is it CRC by any chance ?

Comment: the question does not specify which algorithm to use. Although, I guess that actually uses CRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender calculates checksum to the data are sends it with the data in same message.

The receiver calculates the checksum again to the received data and checks if result matches with the received checksum.

There is still a chance that both the data and checksum got modified during transmission so they still match but the likelihood of that happening because of random noise is extremely low.